# Wordpress plugin for multi-user, multi-profile website

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to create a **upwork.com** like website in Wordpress called **geeksboston.com** and I do NOT know what type of plugin/extension I should use. Basically my idea for the site is something like this:

- I as administrator need to have full control over users/geeks accounts (enable, disable, delete, etc)
- Everything should be free of charge for both "geek" and "user".
- Automatic registration process with email validation and captcha.
- If you are a "geek" you can create your profile entering your experience, resumes, certificates, etc.
- Regular users are not required to register, but can navigate through out the website, look for/contact geeks, etc. But to contract/rate a geek, this user must be registered.

I am new in Wordpress but heard that it can do great stuff. So any clue?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest Ukuu people plugin and WP-CRM. The above two core plugin is for free and It also offers paid add-ons to integrate some features. Please refer the below link. Click [here](http://www.wpbeginner.com/category/plugins/) for more details.